# c# WPF bind combobox to TPH in Entity Framework code first using LINQ

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, linq

I'm building a WPF application using entity framework code first for the database. I need to bind my combobox to a TPH table that has a discriminator for two types of entity.

I've tried to query like this in `XAML.CS`:

```
 var pet = (from Pet in db.Pet.OfType<Dog>()
               select Pet).ToList();
 ComboBoxDog.ItemsSource = pet;
```

And my combobox in `XAML`

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxDog" ItemsSource="{Binding Path = Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="203,81,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="138" Height="28" SelectionChanged="cBoxServer_SelectionChanged"/>
```

If I remove `Path=Name` from `combobox` and `.OfType<Server>()` from my query it's showing values correctly, but without taking in considerations the discriminator. I would like to show only Name attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the DisplayMemberPath ,DisplayMemberPath specifies the path to the display string property for each item. In your case

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cBoxServer" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="203,81,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="138" Height="28" SelectionChanged="cBoxServer_SelectionChanged"/>
```

Comment: Did you change the ItemsSource as above

Comment: Yes, I did. Same awful data in combobox

Comment: Do you mean data inside the table?

Comment: NO, one row that you are binding

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96416/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-koosshh56).